# windows service integration with sql using ado .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado

```
 **public  static void göster()
    {
        SqlConnection connection =GetConnection.GetConnectionObject();


        //TODO parametreleri command.parameters yoluyla alsın
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText= "select * from windowsserv";
        command.Connection = connection;
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");
        SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(rdr.Read())
        {
    ------------------> Console.WriteLine(rdr[0].ToString()+"--"+rdr[1].ToString());

        }

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Hi all, This is my code and also there are more that ı didn't show,I recorded data to sql server. This code block(pointed with arrow) shows all sql server data and ı want to see only last data (recorded to sql server) in console. But ı could't find any answer. Please help.**

Comment: This is a very strange question.  It is impossible to tell from your question what the definition of "last data" should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
command.CommandText= "select * from windowsserv";
```

you can use some SQL Filters and Ordering, like: (This will return last 10 register based on a date filter.. now you need to know what range your (last data) has been recorded to get exactly what you need.
**Replace (date_column) with a column in your table who have this kind of data.**

```
select top 10 * from windowsserv where (date_column) between '2017-09-12 00:00:00' and '2017-09-13 00:00:00' order by (date_column) DESC
```

Then in your code you will have something like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "select * from select top 10 * from windowsserv where (date_column) between \'2017-09-12 00:00:00\' and \'2017-09-13 00:00:00\' order by (date_column) DESC";
```

You can improve your code as well doing this:

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection.GetConnectionObject())
        {
            //TODO parametreleri command.parameters yoluyla alsın
            var command = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = "select * from windowsserv",
                Connection = connection
            };

            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Connection opened");
            var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0] + "--" + rdr[1]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for recommend and also ı used SQL filter. My new code block is """"command.CommandText= select top 1 * from windowsserv order by date desc ;"""""" instead  """""command.CommandText= select * from windowsserv";""""".

Answer (score 0):

try changing your while loop to.

```
    bool isLast = rdr.Read();
    while(isLast)
    {
        string firstCol = rdr[0].ToString();
        string secondCol = rdr[1].ToString();
        isLast = rdr.Read();
        if(!isLast)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(firstCol+"--"+secondCol);
            break;
        }
    }
```